# AWS EC2 Instance OS repair

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, centos

I have Apache server running on Centos5.4 Ec2 instance. Unfortunately while removing Bash from Centos, it also removed basic shared libraries.

Now afterward I can't SSH to that EC2 instance but Apache server is still running (I can access my site through URL).

Any idea how can I get the SSH access back? or can repair Centos Ec2 instance?

Thanks!

Comment: Always create a snapshot before making major changes like this. Makes recovery from errors trivial.

Comment: @EricJ. Yea, learning from mistakes. My instance is also instance-store type not EBS backed. Anyway I can get the data (specially database) now? I have created new instance and tried to attach the disk to new instance but no success.

Comment: @EricJ. And I did the same on Ubuntu machine, no issue there but on Centos, it removed shared libraries :(

Answer (score 0):

You can always contact the AWS support directly. They are very accommodating. send a message to them and they will recover your access, if it is doable from their end.
You may call, or you may send a message from your AWS account.